# How can I run automatically a console app as administrator after code deploy from aws cloudformation services

Tags: powershell

I have written a PowerShell script that starts a c# console app. The functionality of this console app will only work if it runs as administrator.

After code deploy by AWS code pipeline/code deploy service, I want to automatically run this c# console app with administrative privilege.
Is there any approach to do this.

Comment: No. If there was such a way, it would pretty much defeat the entire purpose of UAC.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running a PowerShell script as administrator without typing in passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693327/running-a-powershell-script-as-administrator-without-typing-in-passwords)

Comment: Your question doesn't say which version of Windows you're using. As described [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/how-do-i-change-the-behavior-of-user-account-control-by-using-the-slider) Win 7 allows you to configure UAC, including an option to never prompt. The setting is in Control Panel, User Accounts, Change User Account Control Settings. I see the same setting on my Win10 tablet.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a scheduled task that runs your ps1 script on demand with administrative privileges. Then you can create shortcut or start the task from console or another script. Since user credentials are stored in task itself, it will work without UAC prompt.