# Run Executable File Without UAC Popup as Administrator

Tags: powershell, vbscript, uac, administrator

I am running a large study where we have staff in various countries collecting information on tablet computers running Windows 10 Enterprise.  Each staff member is assigned to a tablet and they log into the tablet with their standard username and password.  These users do not have local admin rights on the machines, but all tablets have a single Administrator Username and Password which I know and these are uniform across the tablets.

Each night, users invoke a program on their tablets that uploads data to our servers and then we pass information back to the tablet during this synchronization process.  Otherwise, they are disconnected from the internet.  At the end of the synchronization process a program is executed that allows me to run any script I like, but the script executes under the standard user account (i.e. without elevated privileges).

I need to update all the tablets with a bug fix for software that they use on the tablets and I'd like to do this during the synchronization process.  The bug fix is contained in a simple executable file that can be easily pushed to the staff memebers' tablets along with any code I like during the sync.  If users were running the synchronization program as administrators, this wouldn't a problem as I could simply run the executable via a script at the end of the synchronization.  But they aren't, so I'm trying to find a way that I could run a script (I don't really care what it is.  It could be a windows batch file, a vbs script, VB.NET, powershell, etc.) and have that script execute with administrative privileges and run the installation without the UAC prompt interfering.

I don't even mind supplying the admin password in plaintext to be honest, since these users are all our employees and they can't really do anything really concerning to us with it (and I could always deploy a subsequent file through the synchronization process to delete the program that has the password in it).  I realize this sounds somewhat complicated, but in a nutshell, I'd like to carry out these steps:

1. Send the bug update executable to the tablet computer (I can do this now)
2. Develop custom code, that will pass admin credentials to the tablet and install the executable in 1 without having the UAC appear (I can send the script to the tablet during sync but do not know how to execute it as the Admin without getting the UAC prompt).

Any ideas how I can do this?  I've explored this all day with minimal success using PowerShell scripts like the ones described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693327/running-a-powershell-script-as-administrator-without-typing-in-passwords) and [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/132e170f-e3e8-4178-9454-e37bfccd39ea/startprocess-verb-runas-credential?forum=winserverpowershell).  This was the closest I got after storing the credentials in `$cred`, but it continued to give me the UAC prompt:

```
Start-Process PowerShell.exe -Cred $cred -ArgumentList '-command &{Start-Process -FilePath C:\MySyncPath\BugFix32.exe -Verb runas}]
```

**UPDATE**

After some additional work, I think I'd be able to get this to run if I could somehow disable to UAC control with a script that can run under the regular user's account and pass the admin credentials to it.  Any idea how I might be able to accomplish this?  If I could get this to work, even with a reboot, I'd be able to accomplish what I need.

Comment: You are asking if you can bypass the UAC prompt? The answer is that you cannot. The "what if this were possible" thought experiment is helpful here. (If it were possible, that is exactly what all malware would do!)

Comment: @Bill_Stewart No, I'm asking if I can supply an administrative password to the UAC prompt automatically instead of having to manually type it in.  Malware would not know the administrative password unless it was supplied.

Comment: No. You can't bypass the UAC prompt even if you know a password because logging on and elevating are two separate concepts. (Even if you log on with an account that is a member of administrators, that doesn't mean you are elevated.)

Comment: Again, I'm not trying to bypass ( http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bypass?s=t ) the UAC prompt.  I'm trying to programmatically accept it.  They are two different concepts.

Comment: `s/bypass/programmatically accept/`. Still the same answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual issue you're having is that you want to update your application, but the application is in the **Program Files** folder (or some other location that standard users are not allowed to modify).

In order to allow any user the ability to update your program, you must grant all users **Full Control** to your folder. Ideally your application's installer would have done this adjustment to the DACL during installation (when the installer was running as an administrator).

For now you will have to settle for a final *one-time* requirement that the users elevate to administrator. Then you can disable all security on your application - allowing any user (malicious or not) to modify your application at will.

```
GrantEveryoneFullControlToFileOrFolder("C:\Program Files\Contoso");
```

with a pseudocode implementation of:

```
void  GrantAllUsersFullControlToFileOrFolder(String path)
{
    PACL oldDACL;
    PACL newDACL;    
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR sd;

    //Get the current DALC (Discretionary Access Control List) and Security Descriptor
    GetNamedSecurityInfo(path, SE_FILE_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, 
          nil, nil, ref oldDACL, nil, ref sd);

    //Create an SID for the "Users" group
    PSID usersSid = StringToSid("S-1-5-32-545");

    // Initialize an EXPLICIT_ACCESS structure for the new Access Control Entry (ACE)
    EXPLICIT_ACCESS ea;
    ZeroMemory(@ea, SizeOf(EXPLICIT_ACCESS));
    ea.grfAccessPermissions  = GENERIC_ALL;
    ea.grfAccessMode         = GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_EXECUTE;
    ea.grfInheritance        = SUB_CONTAINERS_AND_OBJECTS_INHERIT;
    ea.Trustee.TrusteeForm   = TRUSTEE_IS_SID;
    ea.Trustee.TrusteeType   = TRUSTEE_IS_GROUP;
    ea.Trustee.ptstrName     = PChar(usersSID);

    // Create a new ACL that merges the new ACE into the existing ACL.
    // SetEntriesInAcl takes care of adding the ACE in the correct order in the list
    SetEntriesInAcl(1, @ea, oldDACL, ref newDACL); //use LocalFree to free returned newDACL

    //Attach the new ACL as the object's new DACL
    SetNamedSecurityInfo(path, SE_FILE_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
          nil, nil, newDACL, nil);

    LocalFree(HLOCAL(sd));
    LocalFree(HLOCAL(newDACL));
    FreeSid(usersSID);
}
```

It's not completely unheard of for applications to be modifiable by any user: Most MMOs install updates while you play. [MMOs usually have a shim applied by Microsoft that gives](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/UAC-What-How-Why) all users control of the application folder.

Comment: I would suggest that RWXD is preferable to Full Control. But it is good to get past _answering the question_ and instead _solve the problem_.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart That's actually a good note. Everyone doesn't need to be able to modify ACLs on the location; just modify everything *in* the location. Updated the code.

Comment: As noted, this solution still requires at least one elevation and does not constitute bypassing (or "programmatically accepting", if you like) the UAC prompt.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart His alternative, if he wants zero elevation, is to install purely in a per-user location (e.g. %LocalAppData%).

Comment: Right, well, I was addressing the app as it currently (apparently) exists. Fixing the app not to require elevation, of course, solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

run the script as a domain admin account... and set execution policy before the script is run, then run as administrator... some applications are picky about UAC still, but Set-ExecutionPolicy [bypass/remotesigned] will ensure that you're not prompted. however, sharing and permissions may still be an issue if the domain admin account doesn't have access to the share. psexec does this, but it's literally a matter of doing what i just mentioned and the psexec file essentially writes out the permissions by the end of the script. the intent was to make sure that passwords weren't written in clear text, it hashes the password value. either way, if you want this done securely, using a GPO and making sure your file permissions/share is at the highest level might iterate out the prompt. that's why you'll see some batch files use %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9 .... that's because it's automatically requesting elevation and will loop in an iterative cycle until  the UAC prompt isn't necessary.

i know i'm bumping an old thread, but this is what i've found, trying to mix and match legacy cmd batches with powershell ... lots to consider about the execution policy leading into the call vs during the call...

Answer (score 0):

This question is in the category of "when people ask for security holes as features".

You cannot bypass (or, if you prefer this phrasing, "programmatically accept") the UAC prompt and automatically elevate without interactive confirmation. UAC is designed specifically to prevent this. (If this were possible, all malware would do it.)

Comment: Not liking the answer doesn't mean it's not the answer.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't a PowerShell thing but a general windows 10 thing. You'd need to disable UAC for this. No experience with it on Windows 10 yet though.

You can try setting the `EnableLUA` registry key to `0`. The key can be found in:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`

This will probably need a reboot to be active though.

Comment: Thanks.  Right. The problem is, I can't seem to get control of that registry key with admin rights in a script executed under the regular user's account.  Any ideas how I could go about that?

Comment: If they're in a domain you can group policies for that. With UAC on even with admin rights any script you run will probably get a UAC prompt.

Comment: `wmic /user:domain\username /pass:password /node:@"c:\computerlist.txt" process call create "\\server\share\folder\file.exe"` ComputerList.txt is a list of computernames without leading backslashes or IP addresses.

Comment: @Noodles the tablets are not part of a domain.  Would this still work if executed locally on each machine?

Comment: Looks like that solution offered by @Noodles is not viable for local installations as I get the error "User credentials cannot be used for local connections."