Run powershell script without need to enter password
I need to run some script using powershell on Windows Server 2016:
& $ScriptPath\Setup-Server -ConfigPath $SystemConfigPath -Role Servak

Once i run it, at some point i'm asking for the password twice which i need to enter manually (it's the same password).
I want to avoid it and run the script using only command in powershell, without entering the password. I'm not concern about the security issues with that method.
How can i do it?
I need to type the password manually, which i want to avoid.

Please create a new question or add more details, as e.g. (a part) of the contents of the Setup-Server or an [mcve] if the possible duplicate question referred by aditi0404 doesn't answer your question. See also: how to ask.

See if this helps, it has similar ask to avoid password. If you are asking password in your script, you can ask once and save it as an argument and pass in next command.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12694463/10115671
